# chart make draw a line over while Y axis

Tags: c#, mysql, mschart

I have a ranged graph and I need to make a straight line all the way through the Y axis at 8 and 10.

Example of my code:

```
this.CrtPerformance.Series["Range"].Points.AddXY(myReader.GetString("loginid"),
  myReader.GetDecimal("FormulaBOTTOM"), myReader.GetDecimal("FormulaTOP"));
this.CrtPerformance.Series["Top Line"].Points.AddY(10);
this.CrtPerformance.Series["Bottom Line"].Points.AddY(8);
```

but the straight lines does not go from left border to the right itleaves spaces; what is the best way to fix it?

[image]

Comment: If you want to control the x-values you need to add them, so use points.AddXY! You will need one at (0, 8) and one at (4or5, 8) etc.. Since your columns/ranges do not have valid x-values either you may have to change that or associate the some series with a secondary axis..

Comment: maybe i didnt explain myself properly, I've got three chars ( one is ranged chart with Xs represented as ID's from database and Ys is the ranges, two other charts has to be only on Y axes, there is no need for Xs.

Comment: 1) you seem to have three Series in one Chart, right? 2) how can there be a line without a start- and an endpoint?? And how can there be a Point without x __and__ y values??? - But, maybe, you would like to add two LineAnnotations instead. Not exactly easier for a beginner, though.. Do post the Series definitions and code for all DataPoints!